# Jekyll CSS Background image

Tags: css, jekyll

Attempting to create my first blog using Jekyll (practice my css skills too) and its been going good but for a couple of hiccups.

First, background image isn't showing up.  This is what my current style sheet looks like:

```
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 verdana, helvetica-neue, helvetica, arial, san-serif;
  background: black;
  background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
  color: #ececec;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

File Structure looks like this:

```
site 
  _includes
  _layouts
  css
   - style.css
  img
  - background.jpg
```

And I link to my stylesheet in default.html this way:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Still the image isn't being displayed when I navigate to loalhost:4000

Can someone please help me out by pointing to what I am missing/overlooking.

Thank you

Comment: may be it will overwritten with the default styles. try using `important`

Comment: What happens if you use `url(/img/background.jpg)` or `url(img/background.jpg)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was probably just a typo but you have style.css in the file structure and styles.css in the link tag. If that is what you actually have that would be the problem.

Comment: No problem! You might want to mark the question is answered so it gets out of the unanswered categories though.